# Why does the headers option not work for setting Access-Control-Allow-Headers using Middy and Serverless?

Tags: cors, serverless, serverless-framework, middy

I am getting the following error when trying to do a `POST` against my Serverless API that uses AWS API Gateway:

> Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/shop' from origin 'https://otherexample.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field shop is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I tried using the `header` option to `cors()` with `middy`, but this does not work:

```js
const handler = middy(async (event, context) => {
  // ...
})

handler.use(cors({
  headers: 'Content-Type, shop'
}));

module.exports.handler = handler;
```

However, this works:

```yaml
findShop:
  handler: src/routes/findShop.handler
  events:
    - http:
        path: /shop
        method: post
        cors:
          origin: '*'
          headers:
            - Content-Type
            - shop
```

Why does the latter work and not the former? The `@middy/http-cors` docs say the following, so it seems like specifying `headers` in `cors()` should work:

> headers (string) (optional): value to put in Access-Control-Allow-Headers (default: false)

Comment: How did you stack your middleware? The CORS middleware should typically come first.

Comment: That's the only middleware being used.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? I'm having the same problem, it is like the middy cors middleware is doing absolutely nothing